# Memory problems when changing view property on UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using a UITableView inside a popover (iPad) to select an image from the Documents Directory. This image is then displayed in a UIImageView. Here is the code I am using to put the new image into the UIImageView:

```
- (void)changeImage:(NSString *)imageFilename {

    NSLog(@"changeImage to: %@", imageFilename);    

    NSFileManager *fileMgr;
    fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *imagePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageFilename];

    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

    NSLog(@"Path for new image: %@", imagePath);

    self.imageView.image = newImage;
    [newImage release];

    [fileMgr release];

}
```

This always works fine the first time around, but whenever I try to change the displayed image again from the popover, I get the following error:
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

I've narrowed the problem down to this line:

```
self.imageView.image = newImage;
```

I tried adding the following before that line:

```
self.imageView.image = nil;
```

It made no difference. I can't figure out why this works the first time but won't repeat the same behaviour next time around.

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `[newImage release];` from your code and you should be fine!

You didn't alloc/retain/new the **newImage** so you don't have to release it.

It works the first time because `UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];` returned you an autorelease'd object that is valid for the current run-loop but you are over releasing it, and when the run-loop tries to use it again and hence the EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]; - working fine now

Answer (score 1):

BTW you also shouldn't release fileMgr, because you don't own it. Docs say that it is always the same instance (a singleton) - it doesn't break since it is common to override "release" on singletons to do nothing. Still, it doesn't have to be this way and is wrong.

Comment: Good observation -- I missed that one :-)

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't have a deep understanding of Objective-C, but I think you should copy the image:

```
self.imageView.image = [newImage copy];
```

Comment: No need to copy, just don't release the newImage and it will work fine.

Comment: @Damien - thanks for the comment, but wouldn't it break if he has autorelease pool (not challenging, just want to understand...)?

Comment: Challenging is ok, too! In a way it depends on how he has defined the @property self.imageView. But assuming it is set to (nonatomic, retain) then [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath] will return an autoreleased object and setting self.imageView.image to it will then retain it. Auto-released pools wont then dealloc it as its properly retained and is not eligible for collection.

Comment: @Damien - when I know enough I'll challenge, until then - thanks!

Comment: Also just some more FYI.... to use copy the object needs to declare conformance to the <NSCopying> protocol and then implement its only method: -copyWithZone: